# Make XCTestSuite skip my 'abstract' TestCase helper class

Tags: xcode, xctest

My tests all have some functionality in common so I moved them all into a common helper class and derive all my tests from that.

so I HAD:

```
@interface MyConcreteTest1 : XCTestCase
@interface MyConcreteTest2 : XCTestCase
@interface MyConcreteTest3 : XCTestCase
```

I modified the tests to be

so I HAD:

```
@interface MyConcreteTest1 : MyAbstractTestCase
@interface MyConcreteTest2 : MyAbstractTestCase
@interface MyConcreteTest3 : MyAbstractTestCase

@interface MyAbstractTestCase : XCTestCase
```

the thing works alright BUT xcode also lists MyAbstractTestCase in the list of unit tests. It doesn't have any tests and nothing can be run but it is in the list of tests (left sidebar)

so the question is: how can I tell xcode to ignore my abstract class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, there's no way. XCTest discovers tests by introspection, and there's no way to mark a class to have it excluded from this process. I just shrug and put up with the extras.